# WPF: Optimize loading time and memory usage of Canvas having 5000+ elements

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, lazy-loading, software-design

[image]

As shown in the image above, my application has ~5000 elements drawn to a Canvas.

Due to this large number of elements, I've got two problems:

1. Memory usage is ~3 GB
2. The loading time is ~4 minutes

I need to optimize this.

E.g. as shown in the image, we are using combo box to bind item source 5000 with a list of string items.

Is there any way we can use the same items source location instead of creating new one every time for each one of the 5000 elements? That could solve the memory usage issue...

About the loading time, I don't worry so much now.

However, I currently have a progress bar which displays the loading progress of all those elements, but it does not work as expected (it closes before loading). I think it is so because we can't run two STA threads at the same time.

How can I keep this progress bar working until every element is successfully loaded to the canvas? I didn't find any event which informs the successful loading of elements to the canvas.

Any ideas on how to improve this application? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: 5000? How do you even show them all at once? And if you don't, virtualize them!

Comment: We have a zoom bar by which one can see all the element once. What would happen in that case, because virtualisation will not work. Any other solution required instead of virtualisation.

Comment: Well, at one point when you zoom out you won't be able to see very little detail anyway. You could switch the DataTemplate once you reach a certain zoom value to a simpler one.

Comment: @Praveensharma: Well, how can someone see 5000 elements at once? This seems more like a software design issue than a feature... Unfortunately there is no algorithm like LoD (Level of Detail in 3D rendering) for WPF controls yet. The only solution I can think about is data virtualization... unless you engage in creating deeply customized WPF controls.

Comment: I can't even see 100 items?!

Comment: There's a combobox? The picture doesn't look like what you seem to be describing.  I also think virtualising ought to be at least part of any answer. 5000 of anything is going to be pretty tiny if it's on one monitor.

Comment: @Andy I am not showing whole canvas here, this image shows only few elements. Also in a single element we have 3 combo box at top and one text box at bottom. This combo box item source needs to be filled 5000 times, so its consuming space. Do you have any idea how we can bind items sources to single location while rendering the element

Comment: You can just bind itemssource to a resource. If that needs to be an observablecollection then put one in resources.